# How do I create a query that sets true if one or more records exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to create a query like so:

```
@step1_completed = IF 1 or more records exists return true, else false
```

Comment: What is `record`? Is it an instance of a model?

Comment: Not an answer, but why not do `@step1_completed = 1_or_more_records_exists?`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `record` is a model,

```
@step1_completed = Record.any?
```

Comment: I sure like that idea, but it errors: undefined method `any?'

Answer (score 2):

The `exist?` method was made for this:

```
Record.exist?
```

It will do a query to check if a single record for the table exists and will return `true` if it does.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following:

```
@step1_completed = Record.first ? true : false
```

Comment: Just Record.first in this case would return a truthy value by itself. If you wanted to convert it into `true` or `false` just do `!!Record.first`. You don't need to `? true : false`